# How do I get around unsupported characters while web scraping?

Tags: python, web-scraping, lxml

I am scraping a web page with lxml. At one point, I get the content of a table cell.

```
# get last name
lastNameContainer = tableRow.xpath('./td[@class="lastName"]');
lastName = lastNameContainer[0].text
```

Unfortunately, one table cell has a character outside of ASCII's range, which produces this error.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 5-7: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried adding this to the top of my Python file to no avail.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

How can I get around this problem? I still want to store this character. This character, by the way, is either ♀ or ♂ depending on the table row.

---

Update: I realized that the error is triggered when I write the data to a file:

```
with open('myData.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write(lastName + '\n')
```

Oddly, this still produces the above error.

```
with open('myData.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write(lastName.decode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Comment: Is the file you're writting encoded in ascii? I'm not getting that problem when I write ♀ character to a file (I write in UTF-8 by default in Ubuntu).

Comment: By the way, `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` is used only to define the source code (yourmodule.py) encoding (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: Thanks, how do I change the encoding that I write a file in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lxml needs their strings in unicode. When I get that exception I resolve it using `decode('utf-8')`.

ie: `E.doc('♀'.decode('utf-8'))`

Updated:

> ```
> with open('myData.txt', 'w') as myFile:
>       myFile.write(lastName + '\n')
> ```
>
> Oddly, this still produces the above error.
>
> ```
> with open('myData.txt', 'w') as myFile:
>       myFile.write(lastName.decode('utf-8') + '\n')
> ```

Also notice that if lastName is `unicode` and you try to write an `UTF-8` encoded file you will need to convert it back this way `lastName.encode('utf-8')`

```
with open('myData.txt', 'w') as myFile:
    myFile.write(lastName.encode('utf-8') + '\n')
```

Comment: Also, I think my error is being triggered upon writing into a file.

Comment: E is an instance of ElementMaker (a shortcut to build elements): http://lxml.de/api/lxml.builder.ElementMaker-class.html